# how to check a device (mouse, USB-VGA, USB-HDMI) contains no malware

Tags: malware, forensics, usb

I got my fingers seriously burnt with some garbage bought online, which was a USB-3.0 to VGA cable. It contained a driver that requested an install, that led to my computer being unstable and a few other things. Malware was not verified but it led to a factory re-install of the computer being necessary. How to prevent this from re-occurring? (Yes ... use virus checker, dont install anything and only buy recognized manufacturers :S). I am thinking in terms whether there is a risk with plug and play devices and whether I can forensically look at the code in such devices.

Possibly ... I got somewhere there but would be grateful to see any other persons' take on this:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

Comment: It is unlikely that the hardware what the problem, but that's what you asked, and we have duplicates of that question. The problem is more likely the software you installed... And you have provided no evidence that there was malware, so I would caution against jumping to that conclusion. Bad software is more likely than malicious software.

Comment: USB-VGA is not a "cable", it's a whole computer (input-processing-output) and you have to make the OS think it has a video card, which takes a driver (aka software).

Comment: The best outcome I can come up with is to only buy in future from a reliable and recognized supplier.